# TV recording, Sky & Windows Home Server

Tags: windows-media-center, tv, windows-home-server

I’m a totally newbie to home media/automation so am looking for pointers on setting up a central hub for backups/audio/tv and video :)

I have;

- SkyHD+ Box
- BTVision Box
- 2 x Samsung TVs
- Windows Home Server on a self
  build box, will be buying a dedicated
  WHS box when the Vail release hits
- Ethernet 100Mb & Wireless
- 2 x PCs
- 2 x    Macs
- Virgin 20Mb cable broadband.

I’m pretty sure I can get the backups and the audio sorted out but is there any way to use WHS as the central hub for TV? i.e.  save any recordings from the Sky and BTVision boxes to the server then play those on any TV or computer in the house.

If transferring recordings isn’t  possible can I get a tuner card that will take SkyHD and BT Freeview signals to record direct on WHS.

I have about £1000 for the project, is this a realistic amount.

Thanks for any help

Si

Comment: I am very keen to see what guys suggest for saving recordings from Sky

Comment: Sky encrypt their recordings. You can't just copy the files off the HDD in your Sky+ box and play them on your PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to transfer programs from Sky+ to a media server to watch from your PC there is a long winded way to do it. [This](http://www.avforums.com/forums/sky-sky/628813-how-can-i-transfer-sky-recording-my-computer.html) post covers how to do it. However if you're just looking to back up the programs you have on your Sky HD+ box you can use [Copy+](http://www.skycopyplus.co.uk/)

If you're looking to back up the files on your BT vision box then [this](http://community.bt.com/t5/BT-Vision/Download-recordings-from-Vision-Box-to-a-PC/td-p/28168) thread should be of help.

In short though there is no easy way to transfer the individual files over from HDD to HDD and just watch them on your PC. DRM and encryption will prevent you doing this.